# Usage of 'z' in the word serialized in English?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Is it correct to use 'z' or 's' in the word "seriali **z** ed" when writing correct English? (I.e. not a variant of English like "American") Or should it be spelled like "seriali **s** ed" ?

Comment: There is no one correct "English". There are major dialects, like British English and American English. Each has their differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use an **s** in *specialised* is usually the British English spelling. On the other hand, using a **z** is the American English spelling. You can choose which one to use depending on what your audience is. If you are in Europe, it may make more sense to use the British English spelling.

However, there is no such thing as one single, correct English. There are many, many [dialects of English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dialects_of_the_English_language), and even what is known as [Standard English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_English) varies between countries. If an American sees *specialised*, they will understand it, just as most British people would understand *specialized*. Both are versions of Standard English.

Comment: In fact, some southern US dialects are closer to original British English from colonial times than British English is today.  See Tangier Island, Virginia for an example.  British English has undergone many changes over the years compared to their old colonies, especially from being a world imperial power, where the colonies wouldn't be communicating much amongst themselves but would be exporting the local dialects and slang to the motherland.  Also, the Received Pronunciation did a lot to change common British English.

Comment: Very good point, @Phoenix. Are you saying that there *is* a universal "real English", or just emphasizing that all the dialects are different but mutually intelligible?

Comment: There is only original English and everything that has grown out of it, and no one speaks the original anymore. Least not outside of academics specializing in it.

Comment: @Phoenix: what do you mean by "original"?

Comment: Well, I could go with Old English post unification when the various dialects were somewhat codified, but I would probably say Middle English from after the Norman Conquest, as then all the elements are in place.

Comment: @Phoenix Actually, there are Scots who would probably disagree with that statement, or interpret in a way unlike how you might.

Comment: The author wants to know about the word serialized but you talk about the word specialised. Please read the question more thoroughly next time.

Answer (score 4):

As simchona says, there is no single correct English. Every major variety has its own pecularities, and on this particular question at least one major variety -- standard British English -- is itself divided.

In words containing the suffix derived from Greek *-izo*, the spelling *-ize* is required in American and Canadian English and not uncommon in British English: the British National Corpus runs 3:2 in favor of *-ise*, and the Oxford University Press uses *-ize*. The spelling *-ise* is much more strongly favored in Australia and New Zealand, but *-ize* is not unknown.

For further information see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise.2C_-ize_.28-isation.2C_-ization.29), [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_spelling), and [this note](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/13/messages/785.html) by the late Larry Trask.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know but Americans have a special attachment towards z, they frequently change spelling of words with s to z! Don't ask me why!!!

Both are Standard English as @sinchona said..

But this is a matter of your locale, it would depend on where you are residing. British use 's' in specialised while Americans use 'z' instead..

Comment: This is a bit of an oversimplification: *-ize* is a traditional British spelling and still quite common in British usage, albeit less so than formerly.

Comment: The 'z' is the original, as Brian Scott pointed out it comes from a Greek suffix -izo.  American English tends towards original spellings in words and constructs derived from foreign languages.  No idea why the Brits don't.  I think it started with hating the French enough to start changing words with Gallic origins.

Comment: u both seems to be from North America...that's explains the unrest. But hey, I believe English was spoken by English first rather than Americans...

Comment: Just because the other two comments may or may not be from North America, it doesn't mean that they don't understand how British English works. They both make good points; your answer does simplify the issue. Also, just because someone spoke a language *first* doesn't make it uniform.